# POST on many to many Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

models

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11,blank=True,null=True)
    likecus=models.ManyToManyField(smartphone ,verbose_name="лайк")



class smartphone(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Serializer

```
class CreateCustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('phone', 'likecus')
```

I get the error that the required field of Customer is not sent. This setup works for **PUT** call however.

The issue with PUT call is that when I call the PUT call again, it overrides the existing data in the CreateCustomerSerializer relation field with the new data and not simply appends the data of second API call to the first.

How can I POST data so that I am able to link existing smartphone records with Customer records?

**through the Primary Key Related Field. I have this created has not changed. I don't know, some people have solved the problem this way. it doesn't work for me**

Comment: What is A and what is B? Please make it clear.

Comment: @BernardoDuarte Customer and smartphone